# A set of mutations that REGULATE / REGULATES genes

Tags: grammatical-number, relative-clauses, that

I am trying to wrap my head around the usage of 'that' in these two sentences. While I got the answers correctly when I tried to understand the meaning of the sentence, I am wondering if there is any grammar rule that I am missing out here.

1. A study found that many autistic children share a set of mutations that **regulate/regulates** genes known to influence communication among brain cells.
2. The department is taking a stand against an approach that **stand/stands** to make an indebted citizenry more dependent on federal.

In sentence 1, it seems that *that* refers to 'a set'
In sentence 2, it seems that *that* refers to 'approach'. Why does it not refer to 'a stand'?

Is there any rule that I can follow for 'that' in this context? For example, I read somewhere that 'that' must modify the noun immediately preceding it, but in example 1, that rule does not work. Also, somewhere else, I read that 'that' does not modify prepositional phrase. This works for 1 (*of mutations is ignored*), however for 2 this fails since (*against an approach*) is a prepositional phrase.

Comment: "set of mutations" is a noun phrase. There's no simple rule that says whether it refers to the head noun or the whole phrase, it must be determined from context.

Comment: It's possible that in #1 it refers to "mutations". The difference is very subtle.

Comment: "Set of mutations" is not a noun phrase; it's a nominal. Add a determiner and you have an NP: "A set of mutations".

Comment: "I read somewhere that 'that' must modify the noun immediately preceding it" " I read that that does not modify prepositional phrase" both of these are false because they are over-simplifications. In fact, the antecedent of a relative clause is often ambiguous

Answer (score 2):

> "I read somewhere that 'that' must modify the noun immediately preceding it"

This generalisation is a good one - almost. A relative clause *usually* occurs directly after the phrase it modifies. When the antecedent is headed by a noun this means that the relative clause occurs directly after the **Noun *Phrase*** that it is modifying. The word *phrase* there is crucial.

Noun phrases often contain smaller noun phrases inside them. So for example in the phrase *the man of the moment*, there is a smaller noun phrase, *the moment*. So whether the verb *REGULATE* should agree with the noun phrase *a set of mutations* or the noun phrase *mutations* depends on which noun phrase is the understood Subject of the verb. (In this case it doesn't really matter very much)

In the second example, the antecedent for the relative clause could be either of the following noun phrases:

- a stand against an approach
- an approach

It isn't possible to tell which is intended without further context. However, in this case the two sentences will mean radically different things depending on what the antecedent noun phrase is.

Answer (score 1):

The (nested) noun phrases immediately preceding *that* in #1 are:

- mutations; and
- a set of mutations. (cf [BillJ's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381498/usage-of-that-as-a-relative-pronoun-singular-or-plural-verb#comment898532_381498))

There's no simple rule that says whether it refers to the whole phrase or the last of the nested noun phrases. It must be determined from context (*cf* [Barmar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381498/usage-of-that-as-a-relative-pronoun-singular-or-plural-verb#comment898525_381498)).

For example, using nested brackets identify the candidate noun phrases, "*a (school of (children of (farmers))) that*" could be followed by "*conducts exams*", "*sit exams*" or "*grow crops*".

*That* refers to the noun phrase immediately preceding it. In #1, since there are two candidates, it is possible for *that* to refer to *mutations* ([Barmar](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381498/usage-of-that-as-a-relative-pronoun-singular-or-plural-verb#comment898527_381498)), but it's also possible for *that* to refer to *a set of mutations*.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ***set*** regulate genes as a whole, or do the ***mutations***  individually regulate the genes? The verb should agree with whichever noun regulates the genes.

In this case, it seems quite possible that both nouns could be said to regulate the genes, in which case both answers would be correct.

Comment: Actually the sentence is scientific nonsense. Mutations don't regulate genes, they alter them. It is the genes that regulate processes. To retain the problem the sentence could be something like "…children share mutations in a set of genes that regulate/regulates communication…". Then the question in your answer is still valid: is it the set that regulates communication or does each individual gene do so? I imagine we shall never know.

Comment: @David: Actually, your "correction" is still scientifically wrong. It's probably not the communication that is being regulated, it's the ***genes***. And many genes are regulated not by other genes but by non-coding areas of DNA.

Comment: Lack of linguistic precision! Genes are not regulated by non-coding DNA, but by RNAs transcribed from non-coding DNA.